# OneToOne relationship with cascade deleting both sides

Tags: java, hibernate, jhipster

I have project based on JHipster generator. I have two entities: Pattern and File. One pattern has only one file, and one file can be attached only to one pattern. So I think its typical OneToOne relationship. How to delete other entity when deleting is one side of relationshlip? I mean: When I delete Pattern, I want to delete also File. Also, when I delete File, I want to delete Pattern.
I have somethink like this:

```
public class Pattern implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityPattern")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private File file;
}
```

and

```
public class File implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Pattern pattern;
}
```

But it doesnt work. I have org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException exception caused with constraint violations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class Pattern implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pattern",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private File file;
}

public class File implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Pattern pattern;
}
```

I only used JPA compatible code.